# voom fold marker toggle key mapping

Tags: vim

I use Voom a lot, but I would like to map keys for toggle the fold mark.

what I currently have is

```
imap <Tab>1 <esc>$a {{{1<esc>
nmap <Tab>1 <esc>$a {{{1<esc>
```

but I would prefer

```
imap <Tab><number> <esc>$a {{{<number><esc>
nmap <Tab><number> <esc>$a {{{<number><esc>
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for n in range(1,9)
  execute 'inoremap <Tab>'.n.' <Esc>$a {{{'.n.'<Esc>'
  execute 'nnoremap <Tab>'.n.' <Esc>$a {{{'.n.'<Esc>'
endfor
```